# Python how to avoid very similar lines

Tags: python

For the code examples below, what is the best way to write them in less lines? I find the code with less lines more easy to understand

Except for the first example, I simply wrote them in a single line, separating by `;`. PyCharm does not like it tough. It says writing multiple statements to a single line violates a pep.

Code example 1:

```
# x and y are 1D numpy arrays
order = x.argsort()
x = x[order]
y = y[order]
```

Code example 2:

```
allfbest = np.array(allfbest)
allfes = np.array(allfes)
alltrial = np.array(alltrial)
```

Code example 3:

```
means = dict()
mins = dict()
maxs = dict()
stds = dict()
medians = dict()
```

Code example 4:

```
means[fes] = bests.mean()
stds[fes] = bests.std()
mins[fes] = bests.min()
maxs[fes] = bests.max()
```

Comment: Less lines != easy to read. Using `;` for cramming multiple lines into one is absolutely frowned upon in the python community

Comment: I agree with @sisanared and PyCharm! The above statements are plenty clear. Any attempt to reduce the number of lines will make it less readable; not more!

Comment: I see. How about this tough: `means, mins, maxs, stds, medians = dict(), dict(), dict(), dict(), dict()`? Or `means, mins, maxs, stds, medians = dicts(5)`? `dicts` function can be written trivially.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuples, but the code readability might get worse.

```
 x, y = x[order], y[order]
 allfbest, allfes, alltrial = np.array(allfbest), np.array(allfes), np.array(alltrial)
```

I prefer to have lines with different meanings be separate. So I will only do this "tuple-wrap" on initialization but not in something like code example 4.

Comment: In this case readability does get worse. But it actually gets improved in example 3 if you use generator expressions.

Comment: Generator expressions are a good solution for example 3, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

All examples should not be crammed into less lines, excluding example 3, which can be solved like this:

```python
means, mins, maxs, stds, medians = (dict() for _ in range(5))
```

or

```
means, mins, maxs, stds, medians = ({} for _ in range(5))
```

The thing in parentheses on the right is a generator expression, and creates five empty dictionaries, which are then unpacked to the five variables on the left.

Answer (score 1):

One built-in shortcut for your example 2 is certainly [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
lst = [allfbest, allfes, alltrial]
allfbest, allfes, alltrial = map(np.array, lst)  # applies np.array to each element in lst
```

Comment: It doesn't really shorten it up too much, and the readability is compromised. I'd use this approach only if there are more than four items I want to initialize the same way.

Comment: It does shorten it up significantly if you keep those individual variables as a collection of some sort to begin with.

Comment: I agree, but if you're going to unpack them anyway, you're better off just putting them in separate lines.